# Set value text field in Activiti Worflow (Alfresco Model)

Tags: java, workflow, alfresco, activiti, business-process-management

I have a Workflow with 2 tasks, and first task has a model with a text field (wfRepromaq:ObsAnaliseCredito).
I want to show this field on my next task with value informed on my first task when i run workflow in the Alfresco Cummunity.

My Models:

```
1ª Task:
<type name="wfRepromaq:analisarCredito">
        <title>Analisar  Crédito</title>
      <parent>wfRepromaq:iniciarFluxo</parent>
      <properties>
       <!-- Custom field--> 
        <property name="wfRepromaq:ObsAnaliseCredito">
        <title>Observação Analise de Crédito</title>
          <type>d:text</type>
          <mandatory>true</mandatory>
        </property>
      <!-- End fied-->
      </properties>
    </type>
2ª Task:
<type name="wfRepromaq:analiseComercialPedido">
        <title>Análise Pedido Gerência Comercial</title>
     <parent>wfRepromaq:analisarCredito</parent>
      <properties>
        <property name="wfRepromaq:reviewOutcome3">
          <type>d:text</type>
          <constraints>
            <constraint type="LIST">
              <parameter name="allowedValues">
                <list>
                  <value>Aprovado</value>
                  <value>Reprovado</value>
                </list>
              </parameter>
            </constraint>
          </constraints>
        </property>
      </properties>
      <overrides>
        <property name="bpm:outcomePropertyName">
          <default>{ecmrepromaq.com.br/workflow/1.0}reviewOutcome3</default>
        </property>
      </overrides>
    </type>

My Share-Config:
<config evaluator="task-type" condition="wfRepromaq:analiseComercialPedido">
    <forms>
      <form>
        <field-visibility>
          <show id="bpm:workflowDescription" />
          <show id="packageItems" />
          <show id="bpm:comment" />
           <show id="wfRepromaq:ObsAnaliseCredito" />
           <show id="wfRepromaq:reviewOutcome3" />
        </field-visibility>
        <appearance>
          <field id="packageItems" read-only="true"/>
          <field id="bpm:workflowDescription" label-id="workflow.field.message" read-only="true">
            <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
              <control-param name="style">width: 95%</control-param>
            </control>
          </field>        
          <field id="wfRepromaq:reviewOutcome3" read-only="false">
            <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/activiti-transitions.ftl" />
          </field>      
        </appearance>
      </form>
    </forms>
  </config>
```

What i have to do to the  field "wfRepromaq:ObsAnaliseCredito" load with value informed before ?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to do is more on the workflow : 
you need to pass your param in a taskListener (complete event) to your next step :

```
<userTask id="alfrescoUsertask1" name="taskName" activiti:assignee="${initiator.properties.userName}" activiti:formKey="wfRepromaq:analisarCredito">
     <extensionElements>
         <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
            <activiti:field name="script">
                <activiti:string>   <![CDATA[execution.setVariable('wfRepromaq_ObsAnaliseCredito', task.getVariable('wfRepromaq_ObsAnaliseCredito'));]]></activiti:string>
            </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>
  </extensionElements>
</userTask>
 ...
```